# unknown characters in my URL

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, url

I have a domain which worked correctly.

But a few days ago, when I post on Facebook, my link it's not accepted.

So when I go to Facebook Developer, there appears 5 characters in my URL that I don't recognized.

For example:

My url is:

```
http://example.com/blog/my-article
```

But when I put my url on Facebook Developer appears like this:

```
http://example.com/Wnoaz/blog/my-article
```

And this changes constantly, because when I put again on Facebook Developer:

```
http://example.com/NUheZ/blog/my-article
```

I watch the code but I don't have any redirection.

Someone who know what is it?

Comment: What is the real url?

Comment: For business reasons I can't provide the real url :/

Comment: Then it is impossible to help you.

Comment: And what is the url you have a problem with?

Comment: That when you click on a post, and copy the url, then paste in Facebook Developer, appears mydomain.com/AbCdE/my-post.
Where AbCdE is a dynamic string.

Comment: @SantosPerez have you specified an og:url tag in your page ? check on facebook debugger and see the inferred value for that

Comment: @SojanVJose I have an og:url, and this don't hany any string that I can't recognized.

Comment: @WizKid works for facebook :P . so guess he is your best bet. but i guess without the url, can't do much.

Comment: Why not just give us the full url?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your websites URL it's not possible to give you an exact answer.

To find the problem yourself you should use the Facebook URL Debugger at...

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Enter your real URL on the debugger page and it will tell you where it got the URL it's using on Facebook from.

To have a guess I would think it's got the URL from a malformed OG tag, possibly the Canonical URL..